# Pydoc equivalent for Common Lisp

Tags: documentation, common-lisp

I've been programming in common lisp for a while now, and I like how there's so much handy documentation on the language online; the problem is that I'm often offline and can't access it when I need it most.

Is there a PyDoc equivalent for common lisp (or even just man pages for the language) that I can download and use in the shell?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: see also : http://clqr.boundp.org

Answer (score 1):

You can download the CLHS and install it in various ways.

http://www.cliki.net/CLHS

Answer (score 0):

that's an old question…

**edit**: as referenced on the [Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/), we can read the HyperSpecs offline with either Dash (MacOS), [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/) (GNU/Linux) or Velocity (Windows).

- we could ask or add it on devdocs: https://devdocs.io/
- and take the data of the CL Ultra Spec: [website](http://phoe.tymoon.eu/clus/doku.php), [data](https://github.com/phoe/clus-data)

and of course browse the built-in documentation with Emacs (C-h, see the menu).